# Pug Jade: Loop on a nested tag element

Tags: pug

I have a problem with for/each loop in Pug/Jade.
I want to loop and print a nested tag element 4 times. The tag is like this:

```
<div class="profile">
    <div class="id">ID Personne: 1</div>
    <div class="fullName">Nom complet: Full Name</div>
    <div class="description">Description: Some Text</div>
    <div class="initialMoney>Argent initial: 0</div>
    <div class="totalMoney">Argent total cumulé: 500</div>
    <div class="transactions">
        <div class="transaction">...</div>
        <div class="transaction">...</div>
        <div class="transaction">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried with for loop but it doesn't work! It prints only the first element of the array! It shows me only one div.profile tag!
Here is my code:

```
for person in persons
    .profile= person
        .id= 'ID Personne: '+person._id
        .fullName= 'Nom complet: '+person.fullName
        .description= 'Description: '+person.description
        .initialMoney= 'Argent initial: '+person.initialMoney
        .totalMoney= 'Argent total cumulé: '+prettyAccumulate+'Dhs'
        .transactions
            if person.transaction
                each transaction in person.transaction
                    .transaction= transaction.id+' '+transaction.fullName+' '+(transaction.add==true?'+':'-')+transaction.money+'Dhs '+transaction.date
            else
                strong Pas de transactions
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please post the contents of `persons` as well as the result you're currently getting and any errors.

Comment: Persons contains: _id, username, password, fullName, description, transactions
And transactions contains: id, money, operation, date.
I'm getting printed only the first element of the array, and not all element of the array! It's like this syntax that I posted does one iteration and last!

Comment: Hi Haitham, can you edit your question to include the full persons object, and format it correctly? Hard to tell what's going on as it is.

Comment: We'll need to see the route js file that contains your render statement in order to help with this.